# reorder character class data frame column and plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(date.time = c("Fri 00:00", "Fri 23:30", "Mon 00:00", "Mon 23:30", 
                               "Sat 00:00", "Sat 23:30", "Sun 00:00", "Sun 23:30", 
                               "Thu 00:00", "Thu 23:30", "Tue 00:00", "Tue 23:30", 
                               "Wed 00:00", "Wed 23:30"), 
                 Price = c(36.15368, 41.61206, 30.80412, 37.47360, 38.04516, 35.72798, 
                           33.05613, 32.65447, 35.50335, 41.81241, 35.14006, 37.56432, 
                           35.04553, 38.00721))
```

the `date.time` values are of class character and the `Price` values are of class numeric.  I would like to plot the data using `ggplot`. The problem is that the data is in the wrong order.  I would like an order of: `sun, mon, ..., sat`

I have attempted to do this using the following code:

```
my.order <- c(7,8,3,4,11,12,13,14,9,10,1,2,5,6)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(date.time, my.order), y = Price, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line()
```

but I end up getting a strange order that begins at the 'Tue' row of the original data frame. What am I doing wrong?

i would also like to label the x axis and so i have tried the following code:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(date.time, my.order), y = Price, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = 'Day', breaks = df$date.time[c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13)], 
                   labels = c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))
```

But the labels end up in the order of the original data set, while the plot is ordered beginning on 'Tue' as above. How can I get both the data and labels to appear in the order I would like?

Edit:  I think it might have something to do with the levels.  Running the following code

```
df$date.time[c(7,8,3,4,11,12,13,14,9,10,1,2,5,6)]
```

results in the following output

```
[1] Sun 00:00 Sun 23:30 Mon 00:00 Mon 23:30 Tue 00:00 Tue 23:30 Wed 00:00 Wed 23:30
[9] Thu 00:00 Thu 23:30 Fri 00:00 Fri 23:30 Sat 00:00 Sat 23:30
14 Levels: Tue 00:00 Tue 23:30 Mon 00:00 Mon 23:30 Wed 00:00 Wed 23:30 ... Sun 23:30
```

Not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually does what you ask it to do in the first part of your problem: respecting the order of your data in `df`, you assigned position `1` and `2` to the two `Tue` values, which is why `ggplot2` plots them first.

You can see the numbers associated to each element when running the following:

```
my.order <- c(7,8,3,4,11,12,13,14,9,10,1,2,5,6)
reorder(df$date.time, my.order)
```

You can use this vector for `my.order` instead:

```
my.order <- c(11,12,3,4,13,14,1,2,9,10,5,6,7,8)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(date.time, my.order), y = Price, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line()
```

The difference with the method `df$date.time[c(7,8,3,4,11,12,13,14,9,10,1,2,5,6)]` is that in your first reorder method, you **associate a position to each element** of your vector (i.e. 1st element has position 7, 2nd element has position 8, etc.) whereas, in the square bracket method you **define the order** in which elements in your vector come up (i.e. 7th element comes 1st, 8th element comes 2nd, etc.).

You will find that using the square bracket method in your `ggplot` call won't help as `ggplot2` automatically uses the alphabetic order by default, i.e. the order of the data in your dataframe does not matter (the data being strings or factors won't make a difference).

However, if you use factors (which is the default when storing strings with the `data.frame()` function), you can **order their levels**:

```
df$date.time <- ordered(df$date.time,
                        levels = df$date.time[c(7,8,3,4,11,12,13,14,9,10,1,2,5,6)])
# see the new ordered levels
levels(df$date.time)
# visualise as is, ggplot2 uses ordered levels
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date.time, y = Price, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line()
```

For your labels, as the ordering of levels has not changed the order of your data in your dataframe, you still have to refer to their original position. But if you want your original code to work, you can add a step to reorganise your whole dataframe according to the ordered levels:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(date.time)
```

The `dplyr::arrange()` function will take the ordered levels into account, and your rows are now ordered as expected.

Your original labelling method should then work fine:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date.time, y = Price, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = 'Day', breaks = df$date.time[c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13)],
                   labels = c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get Sunday to appear first do this:

```
 df$date.time <- reorder(df$date.time, my.order)
 df %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = as.character(date.time), y = Price, group = 1)) + 
   geom_line()
```

No idea why, but making it a character sorts out the re-order issue.

EDIT: with `as.character()` it looks like the labels works as well?

```
 df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.character(date.time), y = Price, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = 'Day', breaks = df$date.time[c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13)], 
                   labels = c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))
```

Comment: Thanks.  That reorder does not change my `data.frame`.

Comment: its the as.character bit that changes it, not the re-order

Comment: Yes, I have tried the code like you have written it, with the `reorder` of the `date.time` column and then the `as.character` in the `ggplot`, however the `data.frame`, and the resulting plot, are not reordered.

Comment: weird, worked for me...are you using the most up to date R?

Comment: I am using RStudio Version 0.99.902